# Excel vlookup return not available

Tags: excel, vlookup

i want to fill the name column using vlookup, here is my transaction table
[image]

and here is my master file

[image]

yes, they're the same number, but why do my vlookup doesn't return the corresponding name based on looked up value ?

does vlookup comply with data type ? like text, or number, or general ?

i have changing the data type, over and over, and return the same "Not Available"

is there anything wrong with my excel 2007 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is that `VLOOKUP` is looking for the phone number in the first column, meaning in column A. For 'backwards lookup', you will need to use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(Phonebook!$A$2:$A$45,MATCH(B2,Phonebook!$B$2:$B$45,0))
```

`INDEX` is as follows:

```
=INDEX(Range, Row Number, [Column Number])
```

It will return the value a cell from the range `Range` that is on the row number `Row Number` and column `Column Number`. I have put `Column Number` between square brackets because it is optional (you have only 1 column if you have a range that is within A:A for example)

To get the row number, you can use `MATCH` like the above. It works a bit like `VLOOKUP`, but instead of returning the value of the matching cell, it returns the row number of the matching cell (or column number if you use it on a horizontal range).

`MATCH(B2,Phonebook!$B$2:$B$45,0)` thus looks for `B2` in the range `B2:B45` of the worksheet `Phonebook` (`0` stands for exact match) and gives the row number.

Then, you tell Excel to return the value of the cell from the range `Phonebook!$A$2:$A$45` and row number obtained from `MATCH`.

Comment: why does my formula return "not available" `=INDEX(Phonebook!$A$2:$A$542,MATCH(Transaksi!B2,Phonebook!$A$2:$B$752,0))`

Comment: @Cignitor Well, for first, `MATCH` works with one row *or* one column.  So, `Phonebook!$A$2:$B$752` should really be `Phonebook!$A$2:$A$752` or `Phonebook!$B$2:$B$752`, depending on which column you can get a match.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Index/Match` like this:

```
=INDEX(Phonebook!$A$2:$A$45,MATCH(B2,Phonebook!$B$2:$B$45,0))
```

Your `Vlookup` doesn't work, because it tried to find value from `B2` in *first column* of range `Phonebook!$A$2:$B$45`, i.e. `Phonebook!$A$2:$A$45`

Comment: what does `index/match` do ?

update : so, are you trying to say that i have to move the Phonebook-name column to the right side of the Phonebook-phone_number column ?

Comment: it's very similar to `VLOOKUP` but more flexible: `Match` returns relative position of `B2` in range `Phonebook!$B$2:$B$45` and `Index` gets this position and returns corresponding value from `Phonebook!$A$2:$A$45`:

Comment: @Cignitor, `are you trying to say that i have to move the Phonebook-name column to the right side of the Phonebook-phone_number column` - yes, vlookup always searching in _first_ column of target range, that's why `Index/Match` approach is more flexible - you can search in any column