# excel formula if number then vlookup to get text associated in row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I am trying to have an excel formula to check a column if it has a number, I want the text that is associated with it. I keep getting a “#N/A” and I’m having issues figuring out what I’m doing wrong. My formula: `=vlookup(isnumber(N2),$N$1:$O$40,3,0)`

N2 has a value of 500
Q2 has a text of January

The numbers in the N column are not always the same numbers. Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: You might try working the formula [step by step](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to reveal what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vlookup return not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690827/excel-vlookup-return-not-available)

Comment: You are asking `VlookUp` to match check if **True** or **False** (which is whats returned by `isnumber(N2)`) exists in your range (which has to columns) and return the value from the third column (which doesn't exist in your range). If you can provide a screenshot of your sheet, it will help to fix your formula

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I realize the #REF! in the "ISNUMBER" that is because I moved it all closer to be able to view but it normally is referring to N2 and on with the same outcome.

Comment: HamTheBurger, not a duplicate. They were inputting the number and finding a name. I am trying to go down the column and if it contains a number, I get the text. I wouldn't be inputting any numbers to find the text. I am essentially trying to combine multiple rows together in a table and take the necessary information.

Comment: @Zac added the picture of what I’m referring to

Comment: What are you trying to do if it's not a number?

Comment: @MarkS. It would just be left blank.

Comment: @richardjahn I adjusted my answer which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're pulling errors is because of `isnumber` this returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and `VLOOKUP` is looking for a match for *that* word

From what you said in the comment you want to use the formula I have below:

`=if(isnumber(N2),vlookup(N2,$N$1:$O$40,3,0),"")`

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help